# Laravel: Eloquent and Multicolumn index

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm building a site with Laravel 5.7 and PostgreSQL. Question is:

Is

```
Schema::table('the_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index(['column1', 'column2'], 'the_index', 'the_method')
});
```

equivalent to

```
CREATE INDEX the_index ON the_table USING the_method ((ARRAY[column1, column2]));
```

?

If not, is there a way to do this with Eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

Use a raw expression and `algorithm()`:

```
Schema::table('the_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index([DB::raw('(ARRAY[column1, column2])')], 'the_index')->algorithm('btree');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, this is equivalent to `CREATE INDEX the_index ON the_table USING the_method (column1, column2);` I guess? Is there a way to create an index with `(ARRAY[column1, column2])` using Eloquent?

Comment: I also tried to find out that, after searching, no. https://github.com/tpetry/laravel-postgresql-enhanced. It says, eloquent needs to target the lowest common denominator, so it misses tons of features. That package would technically mean you could still use eloquent, but it's now tied to a specific db.